# Finding non-matches on same table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, match

I'm a bit of a novice in MS Access but I've started doing some data validation at work and figured it was time to get down to a more simplified way of doing it.

First time posting, I'm having an issue trying to "only" display non-matching values within the same table i.e Errors

I have a table (query) where I have employee details one from one database and one from another. Both have the same information in them however there is a some details in both which are not correct and need to be updated. As an example see below:

```
Table1
Employee ID Surname EmpID   Surname1
123456789   Smith   123456789   Smith
654987321   Daniels 654987321   Volate
987654321   Hanks   987654321   Hanks
741852963   Donald  741852963   Draps
```

Now what I want to identify is the ones that are not matched by "Surname" and "Surname1"

This should be Employee ID

```
741852963   Donald  741852963   Draps
654987321   Daniels 654987321   Volate
```

I'm going to append this to an Errors table with I can list all the errors where values don't match.

What I've tried is the following:

```
Field: Matches: IIf([Table1].[Surname]<>[Table1].[Surname1],"Yes","No")
```

This doesn't seem to work as all the results display as Yes and I know for a fact there are inconsistencies.

Does anyone know what or how to do this? Ask any questions if need be.

Thanks

UPDATE

Ok I think it might be better if I gave you all the actual names of the columns. I thought it would be easier to simplify it but maybe not.

```
Assignment  PayC            HRIS Assignment No  WAPayCycle
12345678    No Payroll      12345678            Pay Cycle 1
20001868    SCP Pay Cycle 1 20001868            SCP Pay Cycle 1
20003272-2  SCP Pay Cycle 1 #Error
20014627    SCP Pay Cycle 1 20014627            SCP Pay Cycle 1
```

So this gives and idea of what I am doing and the possible errors I need to counter for. The first one has a mismatch so I expect that to Error. The 3rd row has a Null value in one column and a Null in another however one is #Error where the other is just blank. The rest are matched.

LINK TO SCREEN DUMPS
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-5TRrOketfyb0tCbElYSWNSM1k

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE [Surname] <> [Surname1]` also return all rows? Then perhaps the Surnames from one table only look identical to the others, maybe they are padded with spaces or Tabs.

Comment: You may have *[white spaces](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/white-space-the-next-internet-disruption-10-things-to-know/)* in your data. Try using [`Trim` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LTrim-RTrim-and-Trim-Functions-E340CED1-67DF-435F-B078-1527A4EDDEA2) to clean these extra characters from the data: `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Trim([Surname]) <> Trim([Surname1])`

Comment: Well as stupid as I am, you are totally right. I had white spaces at the end of my text. I just re did the query to eliminate white spaces.

Only issue is now I only want to display the ones that don't match and need to identify Null values as well.

Comment: Every body falls on *white spaces*, the smart ones learn from there experience ;) `Trim()` is a basuc when receiving data from an externa and/or unknown system.

Comment: `HRIS Assignment No` has a few `#error` values, caused in the import process/ Have this process handle these errors, and insert them as `Null`s, or empty strings. otherwise, use [`IsError` in an inner `IIf()` function](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_xp-access/error-in-access/7cbf0447-dcf4-4b31-9688-92342666946f?auth=1), to convert them to values you can use: `IIf([Table1].[Surname]<>IIf(IsError([Table1].[Surname1]),"",[Table1].[Surname1]),"Yes","No")`

Comment: I updated the answer. if still errors, handle errors and nulls in `Assignment` the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option handles Errors an Nulls in `[HRIS Assignment No]`:

```
SELECT * , IIf([Assignment]<>IIf(IsError([HRIS Assignment No]),"",Nz([HRIS Assignment No]​),""),"Yes","No") As Err
FROM [pc look up]
WHERE [Assignment]<>IIf(IsError([HRIS Assignment No]),"",Nz([HRIS Assignment No]​),"")
```

Comment: This gives me a Data Type mismatch in criteria expression. BTW I don't need the trim function as I have re adjusted the original query from the source table.

Comment: Yup, `Trim()` can't receive or return a null value. I'll fix my answer

Comment: Now white spaces and Nulls are converted to *empty string* (`""`), witch can be compared with other String values

Comment: Yea still same error, wont work. How about just calling all the columns that don't equal "Yes" as a criteria...

And I would remove the trim as I don't need it now.

Comment: Am I applying this to my original 
Matches: IIf([Table1].[Surname]<>[Table1].[Surname1],"Yes","No"

Not to sure if I'm using both? The first one identifies the non-matches but still displays matches. This second one isn't working at all I get no returns. 
Also this is in Access and not SQL, so as I am a little newby I don't know where to insert this query atm I'm putting it into the SQL builder design area and strictly this.


Massive thanks to

Comment: `IIf()` can help if you need the Yes/No value as a field in the query. You can also receive the a True/False value from the direct expression: `(Nz([Surname],"") <> Nz([Surname1],"")` (assuming no white spaces). Just query: `SELECT *, (Nz([Surname],"") <> Nz([Surname1],"") FROM Table1 WHERE...` Note: [`Nz()`converts Null values to non-null values](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php).

Comment: A type mismatch occurs when comparing fields of data of different types, when one type can't be converted to the other. In the answer I posted all data compared is converted to `String` type, there should be no `data type error`. do you use wrap the data in `Nz()` to avoid `Null`s?

Comment: Hi Thanks Marlan, unfortunately this is now giving me a Syntax Error. Mind you I am changing the table names and columns. The Surname and Surname1 was just an example. And I'm doing the lookup on the table within itself.

Comment: Nothing wrong with mocking field names, we keep our client's data safe... But, if you showed the table and some sample data, now please show the real statement, so we can see Syntax errors etc. or where a type mismatch could be.

Comment: have you checked for the sours of the error? probably somewhere in the import process. have you tried to deal with the errors using `IsError()`?

Comment: Ok this worked but I used Error: IIf([PC Look Up].[PayC]<>[PC Look Up].[WAPayCycle],"In Pay Cycle","Yes") on the HRIS Assignment No field. I tried this on the other fields however they still display a #Error.

Comment: The source data is from two seperate tables where both have Assignment No's however one table may not have the Assignment No and the other might. I'm doing a join on these two table to link the matched Assignment No's and then matching their Pay Cycles. If an Assignment No doesn't exist in one table I would like it to display a "0" value or Blank space. This would indicate there is no need for a match on Pay Cycle

Comment: Ok tried Pay Cycle: IIf(IsError([WAPayCycle]),"No Ok","Ok") Everything that is matched displays Ok, the ones that have an Error still display #Error. Does this mean that the source information holds the Error? Thanks

Comment: What is the source information? My guess is not the actual source information, but the process of importing it to Access. Only a guess... ;)

Comment: I'm importing through a DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim. I don't think that's it, well could be but after I import the table Im joining it to another table which is nearly identical however there maybe missing Assignment No's so when I do this Pay Cycle comparison some Assignments will be missing thus leaving Null entries.

Comment: Ah ok I think I got it. I inserted "Is Not Null" in the Criteria from the source table. This way if there is any Null entries it will ignore the WAPayCycle comparison all together. I have another lookup where it strictly compares the Assignment No. So this can be determined in another validation. I plain to +Append these WAPayCycle Errors to a primary "Errors" query which is the next step...
Big help Marlan thanks. Not sure how to give feedback but happy to.:)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE EmployeeID = EmpID
AND Surname <> Surname1
OR Len(Nz(Surname,'')) = 0
OR Len(Nz(Surname1,'')) = 0
```

Kind regards,

Rene

Comment: This also gives me a Data Type Error. I'm not totally confident I'm doing this right. How is it that I'm getting Data Type Error all the time.

Comment: Smells like a data related issue. Remove the record that reads #Error for HRIS Assignment and run the query again. Does it still show the data type mismatch error?

Comment: Trying to resolve the #Error. I can fix it on the HRIS Assignment No but on WAPayCycle it wont fix. Tired IsError () but still nothing.

Comment: Don't try to resolve it but delete the record. Next, test whether the SQL statement now runs without throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you state *"one from one database and one from another"*.
Assuming you start with two tables (you've shown us a query joining the four fields together?) then this query would work:

```
SELECT  T1.[Employee ID]
        ,T1.Surname
        ,T2.EmpID
        T2.Surname1
FROM    Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.[Employee ID] = T2.EmpID AND
                                          T1.Surname <> T2.Surname1
ORDER BY    T1.[Employee ID]
```

An INNER JOIN will give you the result you're after.   A LEFT JOIN will show all the values in Table1 (aliased as T1) and only those matching in Table2 (aliased as T2) - the other values will be NULL, a RIGHT JOIN will show it the other way around.

Comment: This is a query in Access from two seperate tables and I'm trying to run this function on the query itself. So there is no actual database I'm just extracting the information from one database and one from another. Compiling it, into a query using Access, but now I want to do that validation.

Comment: In that case just change `Table2` to `Table1` in the query and it will join on itself and give the same results.